# Continuous functions show that a function is decreasing

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a continuously twice-differentiable, strictly increasing, and concave (also called concave down; i.e. $f''< 0)$ function such that $f(0)=0$.

A: Show that the following function $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is decreasing for any fixed $t>0$:
$$\varphi(x)=\frac{f(x+t)−f(x)}{t}.$$

Will someone walk me through this problem, please? I do not understand how I prove this problem without any numbers. I also do not understand how to prove this for any $t>0$. Because just by giving an example say $t=14$, that proves the function for $t=14$. How do I prove it for the rest?

Comment: This has nothing to do with set theory.

Comment: Well, its a homework problem in my set theory class. Which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the derivative of this new function. Note that from the point of view of this question, the only variable in it is $x$, while $t$ is treated as a parameter (i.e. as a constant when taking derivatives). So:
$$\varphi'(x)=\frac{f'(x+t)−f'(x)}{t}.$$
Now note that since the given function $f$ is concave, i.e. $f''<0$, we know that the first derivative $f'$ is decreasing. What does that tell us about the numerator above?